# spring tool suite high density screen

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I have a Lenovo Yoga with a High Density screen.  Spring Tool Suite display does not support the high density which makes the icons on the toolbar all but invisible and text is equally tiny.

Does anyone have any suggestions beyond using the magnifier or changing the display density.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're running windows?  Try Settings > System > Display and then change the slider for changing the size of text, apps, and other items.

Comment: I said I didn't want to change the display density because that changes for everything,  its just the STS that has tiny icons and text.

Comment: Maybe our definitions are different.  I take pixel density to mean changing the screen resolution.  The change I posted doesn't do that, instead it changes the scaling ratio of the icons.